# How to stop Gradle for expanding dependencies to expandedArchives?

Tags: java, gradle

Maybe I'm not setting up my dependencies properly, but Gradle insists on expanding all of my dependencies into tmp/expandedArchives which effectively makes Gradle useless.  I need various JARs from WebSphere, and with Ant I would just add them to javac's classpath.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some sort of flag I can provide to my compile dependencies to just add them to the classpath?

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: '../MyEarName/lib', include: '*.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: wasHome + '/lib', include: '*.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: wasHome + '/plugins', include: '*.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: wasHome + '/runtimes', include: '*.jar')
  compile fileTree(dir: wasHome + '/java/jre/lib', include: '*.jar')
}

war {
  webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
  }
}

compileJava {
  options.fork = true
  options.incremental = true
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because options.incremental = true.  Removing that fixed the problem.

Search for hours, finally post to SO, figure out the answer shortly after...